# Jquery - Load() Attribute Value

Tags: jquery, attributes, load

Using `Load()` method, I am trying to retrieve the `src` of an `audio` element on another webpage, not a file. I am trying to place this `src` in a variable. Is this possible to do this with `Load()`?

```
<div id="alpha">
    <audio id="beta" src="https://testsite.com/Audio/123.mp3">
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Either you can pass that 'src' as QueryString in URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this..

```
var srcValue;
$.get("sample.html #beta", function (data) {
    var htmlCntnt = $(data); // data contains your html
    srcValue = htmlCntnt.attr('src')); // here is the value of SRC
});
```

Comment: alert(srcValue); I added an alert to check the src, but it keeps giving me 'undefined'.

Comment: I noticed there could be a timing issue going on as the #beta isn't showing up when console.log(data) is run. How can I set up a setTimeout() to test this with the current code?

Comment: whether you need to repeat the load process ?